# Modelo con ImageField blob en django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Alguien conoce alguna manera de en django crear un Modelo que tenga como campo un ImageField que almacene su contenido como blob en la bd , y que se funcional en la administración que provee django por defecto

Se que existen campos personalizados que pueden heredar comportamientos de otros ya existentes y pensé que talvez la solución seria algo como esto

```
class MiCampo(models.ImageField):
    #…. este es un campo, en algún punto hereda de Field creo

class MiModelo(models.Model):
    campo= MiCampo (upload_to='img' …)
    ….
```

Pero no tengo idea de cómo personalizarlo para que guarde la img en forma de blob en la bd, si es que esa es la solución

Tal ves exista alguno ya creado, que me recomiendan?

Que de ser posible mantenga la selección del archivo mediante una ventana emergente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo si realmente necesitas que la imagen se almacene en la base de datos existe el campo BinaryField.

Como en la misma documentación se comenta, los campos de este tipo no pueden usar directamente con ModelForms ya que por default tiene el parámetro editable como False, por lo que tendrías que escribir manualmente la lógica para poder guardar el archivo.

Y como también menciona en la documentación, hacer esto que comentas es una mala practica en la mayoría de los casos, es mejor que siempre se almacenen en la carpeta media. Puedes ver todo esto aquí: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

Si aun así quieres hacer esto, seria de la siguiente manera:

```
 class MiModelo(models.Model):
    imagen_blob = models.BinaryField() # Guardar imagen  como objeto binario
    titulo = models.CharField()


class Miform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiModelo
        fields = '__all__'


def ejemplo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Miform(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.imagen_blob = request.FILES.get('imagen_blob') # El nombre de tu campo en el template, ejemplo: 'imagen_blob'
            obj.titulo = request.POST.get('titulo')
            obj.save()
            return redirect('inicio') # el url name a donde quieras redirigir
    else:
        form = Miform()

    return render(request, 'ejemplo_form.html' , {'form': form})
```

El form no te va a generar el campo de archivo, tienes que insertarlo manualmente en tu template

ejemplo_form.html

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="file" id="imagen_blob" name="imagen_blob">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Completando a lo que pusiste en los comentarios, si quieres ver la imagen o abrirla en un nuevo enlace necesitas transformarla de nuevo, en el modelo puedes agregar un método que te devuelva la imagen en base64, algo así:

```
class MiModelo(models.Model):
    imagen_blob = models.BinaryField() # Guardar imagen  como objeto binario
    titulo = models.CharField()

    def imagen_encoded(self):
        from base64 import b64encode
        if self.imagen_blob:
            return b64encode(self.imagen_blob).decode('utf8')
        return None
```

En el template donde quieras mostrar la imagen iría así:

template_imagen.html

```
{% if object.imagen_encoded %}
<a href="data:image/png;base64,{{object.imagen_encoded}}">
<img src ="data:image/png;base64,{{object.imagen_encoded}}">
</a>
{% endif %}
```

object seria el objeto que pasas al template, primero verificas que el metodo "imagen_encoded" del objeto devuelva algo, entonces generas un enlace con la imagen base64 y muestras la imagen.

Comment: pero no existe alguna de forma de mantener la seleccion de achivo imagen de forma que salga una ventana emergente, como cuando esta el tipico campo ImageField, y que al seleccionarse se obtenga la ruta y con esto se almacene en el forma de blob (talves como propones dentro del campo BinaryField)?

Comment: gracias por tu sugerencia y tomarte el tiempo de responder

Comment: Ya actualice la respuesta, si te es de utilidad márcala como aceptada para que sirva de futuras referencia para otras personas.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda